# Dev Help - Get SOQL in Map

Tags: soql, map

Need some help creating an apex class. I don't code APEX frequently enough and as such don't know what the proper syntax is for this. I need both of the SOQL statements below to function in the map. Can someone tell me how to do this?

I haven't added the For loop yet but the basic structure is typed out in comments and my goal is typed in the purpose line near the top.

```
global class BCI_Account_State_Count_Rollup implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        /*
Created by MM - 1/25/2016
Purpose - count the state field for each employee on an account and update 
the corresponding state field on the account page. 
*/

                //Create List of active accounts
    list<account> myAccounts = new list<account>();
    myAccounts = [Select ID, Name from Account WHERE Type = 'Client'];
    //Create list of State, Count for State, and Account ID for all Client Accounts
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(ID) ct, State__c st, Account__c acct FROM Employees__c WHERE Account__r.Type = 'Client' GROUP BY Account__c,State__c];

    for ( Account a : myAccounts ){
        //Start Loop



        //Update fields on Account using values in employeeStates list. 

        //Loop
    }
    //End Loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here

1.Writing a map query in apex is as below

```
Map<Id,Account> activeAccounts = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name from Account where ID IN :setaccIds]);
```

> Note that putting a filter is very important since the data in account object will keep increasing and one day your code will stop with error Governor limit exceeded with 50K rows ..

2.The second thing here is you need to use [Aggregate SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) in apex

This will look like below

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Employees__c GROUP BY Account__c,State__c];
```

Now loop over AggregateResult records and collect in a map which should not be that hard but left as an exercise

Comment: map type should be `Map<Id,Account>` shouldn't it?

Comment: So i need to create a list for the ".....ID IN ;setaccIds" code, correct?

Comment: All i am telling is you need filters for your query

Comment: No worries @MohithShrivastava :-)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava This looks like a batch job and he won't have to put any limiting criteria since it will only ever do 200

Comment: @EricSSH You are right .I am not sure whats his requirement but i just want to tell him limitations of directly writing query .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - typo in your bind expression, you have `;`, not `:`

Comment: @crop1645Thanks just corrrected!

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code in the original post. Can someone tell me what the proper way to create the debug statement is? I want to verify the all the results from the SOQL query but once again I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: FYI, my "System.debug('Count for Test Account: ' + groupedResults.get('expr0'));" statement doesn't work.

Comment: groupedResults is a list so your debugs are correct except you need to debug inside a for loop.  check the below  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: Also please note you cannot write a SOQL inside for loop .You will query all at a time and use maps to store results .

Comment: Ok, I have my debug statement working now. I will move my SOQL statement outside the loop.